# Data Driven Listboxes in RFT - Filling out Listboxes if they exist

Tags: java, javascript, listbox, rft

I'm relatively new to Java programming and currently using IBM's Rational Functional Tester tool (version 8.5). Before I start, my programming terminology isn't the best, so apologies if I use the wrong terminology in various places. I have also looked around on the IBM website, this site and various other websites but haven't been able to find a solution for this problem :(

I'm currently trying to create an automated test flow (for a web application) but I'm struggling with 1 particular section.

Here's the scenario: On page 1, I have a set of simple yes/no radio buttons. On page 2, I have a group of listboxes (1 set of listboxes in 1 column, and another set of listboxes in another and both sets contain different information). The amount of listboxes seen on page 2 will depend on the amount of yes/no answers given on page 1. If a user says "yes" to every single question, then there will be a hell of a lot of listboxes to data drive (close to 100).

Currently, I'm using this code to populate these listboxes:

```
TestObject[] listboxes
listboxes = html_application().find(atDescendant(".class", "Html.SELECT"), false);

for(int i = 0 < i < listboxes.length; i++)
{
        GuiTestObject button = (GuiTestObject)listboxes[i];
        RootTestObject boxes = getRootTestObject();
        TestObject[] list = boxes.find(atDescendant(".class", "Html.SELECT"));
        SelectItemGuiTestObject gto = (SelectGuiSubItemTestObject) list_viewFormList2View();
        gto.select(dpString("Identity_Type"));

        RootTestObject boxes2 = getRootTestObject();
        TestObject[] list2 = boxes2.find(atDescendant(".class", "Html.SELECT"));
        SelectItemGuiTestObject gto2 = (SelectGuiSubItemTestObject) list_viewFormList2View2();
        gto2.select(dpString("Identity_Proven"));
}
```

The code keeps continuing in a similar fashion like this, but I can't get it working for every possible case due to 2 main reasons:

A) The object location isn't known until runtime.
B) The information provided on page 1 decides what the user will see on page 2.

Is there a better way to do this then adding several repeating sections of code as seen above? As there coulld be many, many listboxes to data-drive.

I've looked in many places for a solution, but I've really struggled to get this particular piece of logic working.

Any help given is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what your code is supposed to do. In my opinion, `boxes` and `boxes2` are the same objects, so `list` and `list2` should be eqal too. Then you get two equal objects `gto` and `gto2` from the Helper Class which are not related to the objects you searched before.

Regarding A) and B): Since it should be known in the testcase, which information is provided on page 1 it should also be given which listboxes are displayed on page 2. Or do I miss something?

If you want to prevent code duplication you need some kind of link between the listboxes and the datapool, eg.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listboxes.length; i++) {
    SelectGuiSubitemTestObject listbox = (SelectGuiSubitemTestObject)listboxes[i];
    String listboxID = listbox.getProperty(".id").toString();
    listbox.select(dpString(listboxID));
}
```

This takes the ID of a listbox and selects the value from the datapool which is stored with this ID. But I'm not sure whether this is what you need–sadly I have too little reputation to add comments to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear enough. Page 1 asks a user their address, other details etc. Page 2 is the only page in which the objects aren't known before runtime (as the information given on page 1 determines how many listboxes they will see on page 2). 

About 'boxes' object: I wasn't sure if a 'GuiTestObject' could reflect multiple instances of an on-screen object (in this case listboxes). Java is my first progrmming language and have little to no knowledge of it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide better solution framework to your problem i would need to you to answer the following queries based on below scenario:
Consider the scenario where the user selects 2 radio buttons as true/yes , which results in 5 list-boxes/combo-boxes in the second page.

1. Do you know how many list-boxes will be there in next page? ( in this case 5)
2. Do you know what item is to be selected in each list-box? Is this data selection coming from a datapool or excel sheet?
3. If you don't know the answer to point 1 how mare you planning to select the items in the list-boxes . What i mean to ask is how would you know how much data you need to feed for this page from the datapool?

Depending on your answer i can suggest a framework or code snnipet.